# equivalence relation and lexicographic order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a HW question

Let $A = \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \ \mathbb{Z}^ +$. Define $R$ on $A$ by $(x_1,x_2)R(y_1,y_2)$ iff $x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2$. Is $R$ an equivalence relation on A.

I dont think It is as simple as to show that the reflexive, symmetry and transitivity hold on $x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2$ for all $\mathbb{Z}^+$ but rather something do with lexicographic order (but i could be wrong).

I am mostly looking for a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you using '$*$' here to signify the Cartesian product?  If so, the usual notation is $\mathbb{Z}^{+}\times\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: yes I am, I wasnt sure on the correct notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* (After you correct a probable typo in your definition,) the relation is of type $aRb\iff f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: soI HAD MADE A ERRor it was supposed to be $A = \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \ \mathbb{Z}^ +$ does that change anything

Comment: @KjTada The proof for question 4 might as well benefit (be shortened to a one-liner) from noticing that $aRb\iff f(a)=f(b)$, with $f(x,y)=2x+3y$.

Comment: soI HAD MADE A ERRor it was supposed to be $A = \mathbb{Z}^+ \times \ \mathbb{Z}^ +$ does that change anything. I had i written as $A = \mathbb{Z}^+ * \ \mathbb{Z}^ +$

Comment: @KjTada Your edit produced the question that I already assumed you wanted to ask. :)

Comment: thanks so much, I really appreciate your help.